# Removing orr workaround for sbt 0.11

Tags: sbt

I am maintaining some code that has something similar to this double-layered workaround in it:

```
import AssemblyKeys._   
lazy val assemblySettings: Seq[sbt.Project.Setting[_]] = baseAssemblySettings

implicit def wrapTaskKey[T](key: TaskKey[T]): WrappedTaskKey[T] = WrappedTaskKey(key) 
case class WrappedTaskKey[A](key: TaskKey[A]) {
  def orr[T >: A](rhs: Initialize[Task[T]]): Initialize[Task[T]] =
    (key.? zipWith rhs)( (x,y) => (x :^: y :^: KNil) map Scoped.hf2( _ getOrElse _ ))
}

lazy val baseAssemblySettings: Seq[sbt.Project.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  test <<= test orr (test in Test).identity,
  test in assembly <<= (test in Test).identity,
)
```

(from [here](http://eed3si9n.com/sbt-010-guide)).

How should I completely remove both "layers" of this workaround, since they apparently aren't needed any more in sbt >= 0.12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure even the or is still necessary though.

It's no longer necessary.

### or

`or` was a workaround for [#202 (Task-scoped keys)](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/202) that worked in sbt 0.10. This but was fixed in sbt 0.12 according to the comment. Let's test this in sbt 0.13:

```
helloworld> set test in Compile in compile := {}
[info] Defining helloworld/compile:compile::test
helloworld> inspect test
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Executes all tests.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/eed3si9n/work/helloworld/}helloworld/test:test
....
```

So we are in the clear with #202. In fact I took the `or` rewiring out of sbt-assembly last week (9/28/2013) for 0.10.0, and now it looks like this:

```scala
// test
test in assembly := (test in Test).value,
```

### orr

The `orr` was a workaround for [#204 ("Reference to undefined setting" while using an optional key)](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/204), which broke `or` in sbt 0.11.0 and was fixed in 0.11.1 according to the tag. Since we no longer need `or`, this is sort of a moot, but we don't need `orr` after sbt 0.11.1.

To avoid further confusion, I removed the section from the unofficial guide and linked to the github for historical interest.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the logs of sbt-assembly, what is done there is simply removing `wrapTaskKey` and `WrappedTaskKey` and replacing `orr` with `or`.

I'm not sure even the `or` is still necessary though. But I don't understand this code at all.